# Sort files by LoC - sort not working when piped from wc -l

Tags: pipe, sort, wc

I'm trying to sort a directory of files by LoC.

But `sort` appears to do nothing if the lines are piped in:

```bsh
paths=`find ./src/ | egrep "\.(cpp|h)$"`
for path in $paths; do
wc -l $path | sort -n;
done
```

Results in something like this (pre-sorted by `find`, but the `wc` numbers are ignored):

```bsh
50 /a/a.cpp
10 /a/a.h
200 /b/b.cpp
13 /b/b.h
...
```

If I use sort on a file instead of a pipe:

```bsh
for path in $paths; do
wc -l $path >> test.txt;
done

sort -n test.txt
```

it *does* work:

````bsh
```bash
10 /a/a.h
13 /b/b.h
50 /a/a.cpp
200 /b/b.cpp
...
````

Why does the pipe version not work?

Answer (score 0):

You’re piping each individual `wc`’s output to `sort`, separately. If you move the pipe to handle the complete output of the loop, it should work:

```bsh
paths=`find ./src/ | egrep "\.(cpp|h)$"`
for path in $paths; do
wc -l $path
done | sort -n
```

[You should avoid looping over `find`’s output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/86440); you also don’t need to use `egrep` to filter `find`’s output. You can process all the above with

```bsh
find ./src/ \( -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.h' \) -exec wc -l {} \; | sort -n
```

or more efficiently, if you don’t mind having a “total” line, with

```bsh
find ./src/ \( -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.h' \) -exec wc -l {} + | sort -n
```

(This still won’t quite work if your filenames include newlines.)

Answer (score 0):

Your first loop sorts the single line output of each `wc -l` individually, and outputs that one after the other. Doesn't work (and that's expected!).

Your second approach first aggregates all lines from all `wc` calls, and then sorts them: that's the right way to go. Whether or not there's a file in between is not the problem here – the problem is that in your first loop you're not actually sorting anything.

So,

```bsh
( for path in $paths; do
wc -l $path
done ) | sort -n
```

should work.

Your `find` call is strange in that it uses egrep to filter the output (which will lead to interesting results the way you do it with folders that end in .cpp, as you'll sometimes find them in e.g. CMake builds) instead of simply `find -type f '(' -iname '*.cpp' -o -iname '*.h' ')'`; however, I'd discourage you from using `find` here alltogether, because file names with spaces (extremely common), newlines etc will break all this, for no good reason.

Instead, use what your shell (which I guess is bash) gives you directly:

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob ## don't fail on empty globs
shopt -s globstar

for path in **/**.{h,cpp} ; do
  wc -l "${path}"
done | sort -n
```

We can make this even shorter, in fact:

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob ## don't fail on empty globs
shopt -s globstar
wc -l **/*.{h,cpp} | sort -n
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU implementations of the `find`, `wc` and `head` utilities, assuming file paths don't contain newline characters:

```
{
  find . '(' -name '*.h' -o -name '*.cpp' ')' -print0
  printf '%s\0' /dev/null
} |
  wc -l --files0-from=- |
  head -n -2 | # remove up to 2 trailing lines to remove the /dev/null
               # and possibly "total" lines
  sort -n
```

Contrary to the `-exec wc -l {} +` approach, this one guarantees that only one "total" line is output.

We still have a problem that `wc` only outputs a `total` line if passed more than one file.  Here, we work around it by adding an extra `/dev/null` which we remove at the end.